# Difference between SCSS variables and CSS variables?

Tags: css, sass

I don't understand the difference between [CSS custom properties (variables)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties) and [SCSS variables](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/variables) (I am new to Sass by the way).

If this CSS code:

```css
:root {
    --someColor: coral;
}
  
body {
    background: var(--someColor);
}
```

achieves the same results as this SCSS code:

```scss
$someColor: coral;
    
body {
    background: $someColor;
}
```

Why were SCSS variables introduced? Are they really the same as CSS variables, or am I missing something?

Comment: Refer : https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/what-is-the-difference-between-css-and-scss/

Comment: @Sid I did refer to that, it does not answer my question which is specifically what is the difference between SCSS variables and CSS ones (and not the general difference between SCSS/CSS), thank you nevertheless!

Comment: It’s all in the browser which you could manipulate css variables And the browser will automatically change it.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

SCSS is a preprocessor. That means it is not CSS, but is converted into CSS at 'compile time'. In the resulting CSS code there is no resemblance to the original SCSS code. Hence you cannot change the variable values at CSS 'runtime'.

Historically SCSS is a fairly old technique. Actually it dates back to as far as 2007. It was invented by the motivation that CSS lacks certain features amongst which are variables (and nesting and loops and mixins etc.).

CSS variables are a quite recent addition to the CSS standard (The last call working draft seams to be from 2014). They didn't render SCSS variables useless, because you can do things to SCSS variables which you can't do with CSS variables (to my knowledge) like color calculations.

On the other hand you can do things with CSS variables that you can't do with SCSS variables like changing at runtime.

BTW: CSS variables are not the official jargon. They should be called custom properties. But everyone calls them variables.

### Addendum 1

One difference I was not talking about. You can't change SCSS variables with JavaScript. CSS Custom Properties however can be accessed and changed with JS

### Addendum 2

This article on CSS Tricks has a good overview: https://css-tricks.com/difference-between-types-of-css-variables/

Comment: That explains why the compiled SCSS replaces the occurrences of the variable with its value instead of using the CSS custom properties!
So you are saying it is due to historical reasons, because SCSS variables were introduced before CSS custom properties?

Comment: Historical reason is one point yes. The calculation is another

Comment: the term *variable* is indeed official but probably not used correctly. We talk about *cascading variables* and *custom properties*.  These two features (defined in the same specification : https://www.w3.org/TR/css-variables-1/) are reduced to be called *CSS variables*

Comment: @yamanidev IMO, it's a bit wrong trying to compare both because they aren't the same at all. They only have in common the *variable* term nothing more.

Comment: @TemaniAfif As I understand the spec: In the term `--my-prop: 10px` the left of the colon is the custom property and the right of the colon is the cascading variable?

Comment: kind of but it's the use of  `var()` that make it a cascading variable. Somewhere in the Spec you can read : *Note: While this module focuses on the use of custom properties with the var() function to create “variables”, they can also be used as actual custom properties, parsed by and acted on by script.* <-- 95% of the use cases use `var()` combined with custom property but we can stop at the custom property feature and we no more talk about variables. Don't have any example actually but we can find use cases where we don't need to use `var()`

Comment: @TemaniAfif I understand your point, SCSS and CSS are completely two different technologies, it's comparing a table with a chair. The reason behind my comparison is confusion; from what I understood, SCSS was developed to easily write styles by introducing different features, like variables. But if the latter already exists in CSS, why bother with another way to achieve the same purpose. Thankfully, yunzen provided a clear and well written answer, thank you again!

Comment: @yamanidev no, they don't achieve the same purpose at all. That's the trap where everyone fall. CSS variables aren't in any way a replacement to SASS variables. They are two orthogonal feature. You may not notice the difference if you are new to CSS but when you will work with them for too long you will understand what I mean.