# Overhead of CSS variables VS SCSS

Tags: css, sass

I have read many posts [Like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67016460/difference-between-scss-variables-and-css-variables) That talk about the similarities and the pros / cons of using SCSS `$` vs using  `custom properites` or `var()` in CSS.

I get all that and I understand the gist.  My question is:  Is there any overhead or degradation by forcing the browser to parse CSS variables, vs compiling the CSS and the browser just displaying the native css outputted by SASS.

We are starting a large scale project, and I am OK using `custom features` as I don't see a need for SCSS any longer since CSS introduced the usage of variables.  I am just worried that this puts an unnecessary burden on the browser when we can just compile one time and the variables are parsed.

Am I being too analytical about this or is there something to placing the burden on the browser?

Comment: SCSS doesn't replace CSS. It compiles **TO** CSS - so saying _I don't see a need for SCSS any longer since CSS introduced the usage of variables_ doesn't really make much sense, since you can put CSS variables in a SCSS file to compile to CSS.

Comment: I think you're missing the point of my post ..  Yes you can use them together, or JUST SCSS or JUST CSS .. But I am simply asking whether the ownness being put on the browser vs compiling variables is negligible when you have, say, 20k lines of CSS.  This is not opinion based . I am asking is there any hard evidence of performance degradation in burdening the browser with variables `var()` vs compiling them into SCSS using SASS variables `$`.  I never mentioned using `var()` IN SCSS

Comment: Actually this is opinion-based because it depends on your opinion of what constitutes a (presumably undue) 'burden' on the browser. Every byte of data a browser has to process is a "burden" technically but it's also the browser's _job_. Where you draw the line and start to complain depends on (ideally) the person footing the bill for the website's creation/maintenance; they should expect a certain performance level; if one isn't specified, then you shouldn't worry about it. if it is specified, test against that metric and if it passes, then you're fine.

Comment: SCSS compiles to CSS. SCSS is just a method to write CSS in a logical, block-level nested way. It doesn't matter if you use SCSS or write in plain CSS, the outcome would be the same: a CSS file. You can use `var(--custom-property)` in your SCSS, since it will output to the exact same thing as if you wrote in a plain CSS. If you are asking if a static variable (`$`) that compiles to a specific value would _cost_ the browser less than a custom property that can potentially update - then yeah, that's a different question.

Comment: @disinfor -- That is exactly what I am asking ..  Whether using `var` INSTEAD of a static `$` will cost the browser more --  And if so . How much more?

Comment: Then I think your question needs to be updated a bit, since this isn't necessarily a SCSS issue. It's merely if multiple static CSS values for a property is less/more "costly" than a CSS `custom property` value.

Comment: I know you understand SCSS or SASS is far more than just variables.  Remember that all SCSS variables are parsed into CSS long before the CSS hits the HTML. Your page never see's scss, just css

Answer (score 3):

So there have been some tests regarding the performance of regular CSS —compiled from SCSS or otherwise— vs CSS w/ Custom Properties. I've done some myself with ~5k CSS variables on 10k+ HTML nodes. Those figures are similar to some of the other few articles I've seen. The performance delta is ~0.8% slower with custom properties. It's not 0, but insignificant for most reasonable use cases; we're talking >50ms differences.

I believe the actual performance issues come with style recalculation when changing variables via JavaScript. If you're using a variable declared on a parent, that is then changed, the browser will recalculate **all** of child elements using said variable. So better scoping and `setProperty` > inline styles (making changes to the HTML attribute) can give you better performance in that scenario.

---

Here's an interesting post on performance with this on Chrome, specifically: [Improving CSS Custom Properties performance](https://blogs.igalia.com/jfernandez/2020/08/13/improving-css-custom-properties-performance/).